# WP_Query cpt taxonomy not loading posts

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have created some taxonomies and post_types trough `custom post type UI` plugin. 
I pass taxonomy_id with a form to a page and I receive it correctly [`var_dump($_POST)`] shows me number example `30`. I want to show posts from that custom post type category: I tried the code below but it returns nothing.

```
$args = [
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'school_type',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => array('30','22'),
            // 'operator' =>  'IN'
        ),
    'post_type' =>  'school',
    )
];
if($q->have_posts()):
    while($q->have_posts()){
        $q->the_post();
        echo the_title();
    }
else:
    echo 'nothing';
endif;
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You have the `post_type` in the `tax_query` array, plus you're targeting `$q` when it doesn't exist (not that I can see. anyway).

Try something like this :-

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'school',
    'tax_query'     => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'school_type',
            'field'         => 'term_id',
            'terms'         => array('30','22'),
        ),
    ),
    'numberposts'  => -1
);
$q = new WP_Query($args);
if($q->have_posts()):
    while($q->have_posts()){
        $q->the_post();
        echo the_title();
    }
else:
    echo 'nothing';
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a $arg variable like this and then use the WP_Query() object to get your posts.

```
   $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'school',
        'posts_per_page'=>30,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => array(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'school_type', 
            'field' => 'term_id', 
            'terms' => array('30','22'), 
    );

    $q = new WP_Query($args);
     if($q->have_posts()):
            while($q->have_posts()){
                $q->the_post();
                echo the_title();
            }
        else:
            echo 'nothing';
        endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `$q = new WP_Query( $args );` before your if line

Answer (score 1):

change your permalink to post type and update permalinks, hope this will help.

Comment: how i change it? 
i added this code to a custom page template.

Comment: go to settings->permalinks->chnage the permalink to post name and update permalink structure.
and add $q = new WP_Query($args); this before if condition in your code.